# Mongodb auto create index for new collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a Node.JS server with a Mondodb database. Multiple clients use this same database, and each client has his own collection. The collections are named by the id of the client.

Since every client uses a different name for his data, when a new client  connects to the server, the first operation he does on the database will create a new collection for him.

I need all the collections to have a specific index. Is there a way to automatically create this index for every new collection?

Comment: [`ensureIndex()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#ensureIndex) or [`createIndexes()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#createIndexes)?

Comment: I know what command create an index. The question is how to have the index created automatically, since I don't know when the collection is created.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, there is no such command.

But don't be afraid to call `createIndex` too often. [The documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) guarantees that when an index with the same settings already exists, nothing will happen. So you can attach it to some common database operations executed by new users. It's no big deal when it gets called more than once.

To highlight this behavior, the method used to be called `ensureIndex`, but that name is deprecated.

By the way: Having a different collection for every client is a quite unusual architecture. It has some drawbacks, like the problem with indexes and other collection-level configuration you already discovered, but also others like being unable to do any queries which use data from more than one client. With the default storage engine, there is the advantage that clients can not lock each other with collection-wide locks, but when you use the WiredTiger engine, that advantage is obsolete because WiredTiger locks only on document level.

A more conventional approach is to have one collection for all users and have a field in each document which says which user owns the document and which is part of all indexes used by user-specific queries.

Comment: I like your approach of having another field. This way I will have the index include the user id. Will it add a lot of overhead to have an index on multiple fields rather then just one?

Comment: @Asher It's still a single binary tree, just with a longer key length.